# Mercado Libre API, como superar el limite de 1000 ítems

Tags: api, mercadolibre

Estoy armando consultas con la api de Mercado libre y veo que solo me trae 1000 items, por mas que el resultado sea mucho mayor. Hay alguna forma de sortearlo o es algo construido en la api definitivamente?

Un ejemplo https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q&q=jurassic+park

Lo cual da

paging: {
total: 1510,
primary_results: 1000,
}

Ese primary_results es el "problema"

Comment: https://developers.mercadolibre.com.ar/devsite/paging-results-global-selling
vas iterando pidiendo paginas

Comment: @aloMalbarez si trate de trabajarlo con el offset, pero siempre puedo jugar y navegar dentro de los primary_results, es decir 1000 items

por ej si pones el offset en 950 esta bien, pero si lo pasas a 960 da error de privacidad  "the requested offset is higher than the allowed for public users. Maximum allowed is 1000",

ejemplo: https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?q&q=jurassic+park&limit=50&offset=960

Comment: Opción 1: filtrar la búsqueda por categoría, esto traería menos productos y podrías recorrer, ejemplo https://api.mercadolibre.com/sites/MLA/search?nickname=tomy+librerias&category=MLA432155
Opción 2: hacer scraping de la web para obtener todos los IDs de productos y luego consultar a la api
Opción 3: Utilizar el acces token del usuario, esto permite recorrer con un offset mayor a 1000.